# Electrical current on machine and power socket

Tags: power-supply

I would like to check if my machine is 220V and drawing a max current of 16A . My power socket is producing 220V with a 13 A fuse in it . Will this cause the machine to trip or cause any fire hazard to the power socket ?

Comment: Just checking, is that 16A @ 220V (about 3.5kW) or is it 16A at a lower voltage (say 12V) produced from the 220V supply?

Comment: It is 220v @ 16 A. There fore ( 3.5kw) is supply to the machine .

Answer (score 1):

If the machine is drawing 16 amps, the 13 amp fuse in the socket will eventually open and shut down the machine. Assuming that the fuse is the proper one for the power socket, there will be no fire hazard.

Comment: Thanks Charles.  The machine in idling mode will be drawing less than 13A . However when during full efficiency , the machine will activate full function and draw up to max of 16A for about 1-2 mins . Will the fuse open and shut the machine down during this instant monent ? If it open, what should I do to lower the machine current drawn to below 13A in order to allow the machine to work as per normal?

Comment: It is unlikely that the fuse will not open during one 1-2 minute work cycle but you need to consider the length of the idle period between work periods. If you have the brand and part number of the fuse, you can check the fuse curve. Is the fuse just for the one socket? Are there more sockets on the same circuit with a common fuse or circuit breaker?

Comment: It is great to hear that the fuse will not open for 1-2 minutes . The idle period is depending on operator where they are going to use as it could be 10-50 mins period of idling time. The machine is equipped with 3 circuit breaker which 3 kinds of application will be connected with . ( eg. Dryer , freeze and warming ) . The main power plug from the machine will be connected to the socket wall that supply 220V of 13A fuse . If the power cable and 13A fuse does not open and trip the machine power, then I will not change the load current to 13A instead of the original 16A current as advised. –